# get the tag name of object returned by getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, html, dom, meta-tags

so suppose I call `document.getElementsByName("title");` in javascript

and I want to know the type of the tag of the element that is returned by that function, for instance, to see if it's a meta tag or a div tag or a span tag, etc

how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("title");` returns a set of elements not a single element
so within a cycle you could use `element.tagName` to get the tag

basicly

`document.getElementsByName("title")[0].tagName` should work

Answer (score 5):

You have returned a `NodeList` object, so you would need to be more specific with your selector, or choose the first element using an index of 0, as in the other answers.

Whilst you can use `nodeName` or `tagName`, `nodeName` is the better option.

Comment: Why is it better?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tagName` property like so:

`document.getElementsByName('name')[index].tagName;`

You need the index as the `getElementsByName` function returns an array.